# Is there a way in TypeORM to make a join table for a many to many relationship into an entity similar to ActiveRecord?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

For example I have a Guardian entity with a Student entity. I would like to configure their many to many relationship in TypeORM as another entity. Let's call it StudentGuardianRelationship. Why? Because we need to show what kind of relationship a guardian has towards a student e.g. parent, aunt, grandparent, and so on.

In Rails' ActiveRecord this is accomplished via 'through':

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Does TypeORM support something like this or is the only possible way to have both Student and Guardian each have a oneToMany with StudentGuardianRelationship?

Answer (score 1):

A many-to-many relationship can be decomposed into two many to one (to many) relationships

Student -> StudentGuardianRelationship <- Guardian

As of yet - there isn’t a way to do this directly.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear, but I am aware of that solution. If you append to your answer to "No there is no Through mechanism for typeorm yet... but you can do this:" I'll just pick yours as the answer